# Why mac os x does not set uid bit for /usr/bin/passwd

Tags: osx, setuid

A lot of books state that examples of setuid bit usages include passwd, at etc. But in mac os x el capitan, the /usr/bin/passwd does not have the bit set.

How could it change the /etc/passwd file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OSX, `/usr/bin/passwd` does not write directly to the password file.  Instead, it uses a *"directory system"*, e.g., a database or LDAP server (e.g., for networking credentials).  To do this, it communicates with a privileged process.

The manual page for the program [`passwd(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/passwd.1.html) is a good starting point.  It lists [`passwd(5)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/passwd.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/passwd) (file format) which mentions

> Processes generally find user records using one of the getpwent(3) family of functions.  On Mac OS X,
>   these functions interact with the [DirectoryService(8)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/DirectoryService.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/DirectoryService) daemon, which reads the /etc/master.passwd file
>   as well as searching other directory information services to find user accounts.

DirectoryService notes that *it* is obsolete, and that you should read [opendirectoryd(8)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/opendirectoryd.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/opendirectoryd), which in turn says

> Open Directory forms the foundation of how Mac OS X accesses *all authoritative configuration information* (users, groups, mounts, managed desktop data, etc.).  This allows use of virtually any directory
>   system via Apple and third party modules.

and

> Open Directory Server utilizes OpenLDAP which is included as part of Mac OS X Client, Mac OS X Server,
>   and Darwin. OpenLDAP provides a robust and scalable platform for serving directory-based information
>   for both *standalone* and networked systems.

So ultimately (even for standalone systems), it seems that `passwd` talks to an LDAP server which stores your credentials.  Looking at output from `ps`, it seems that might be

```
/usr/libexec/opendirectoryd
```

While `passwd` *can* update `/etc/passwd`, in practice it does not do this for your user account.  It uses `/etc/passwd` and [`/etc/pwd.db`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pwd_mkdb.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/pwd_mkdb) only for "legacy" applications (things that have not been converted to Open Directory).